# How to change the state of a checkbox by checking another checkbox in Microsoft Lightswitch

Tags: silverlight, checkbox, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am experimenting with a desktop app built with Microsoft Lightswitch (currently working with VS2013). I have one screen for "Contacts" with various controls and an option to hide that contact (instead of deleting it in case of future "resurrection"). Respectively I have a screen with the hidden contacts.

What interests me is how to change the value of one checkbox on that screen based on the value of another checkbox?

[image]

So when I set the "Hidden" to true, the "Billing Active" and "Customer Reporting" are automatically set to false.

What I have so far is the following:

```
    partial void Contact_Changed()
    {
        // Write your code here.
        this.FindControl("Hidden").ControlAvailable += Customer_Hidden;
        this.SetDisplayNameFromEntity(this.Customer);
    }

    private void Customer_Hidden(object sender, ControlAvailableEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox p = e.Control as CheckBox;
        bool ap = p.IsChecked.Value;
        //bool p = System.Convert.ToBoolean(e);
        switch (ap)
        {
            case true:
                this.FindControl("ContractActive").IsVisible = false;
                break;

            case false:
                this.FindControl("ContractActive").IsVisible = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

The name of the "Billing Active" checkbox is "ContractActive"

And this does not accomplish anything. The whole purpose of the thing is sort of **validation**, i.e. once you get rid of someone, don't forget to exclude him from everything else :) I could also display a modal window popup with a warning or something, but first I am interested in that perhaps trivial problem.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Found how to control the checkboxes when they are on the same screen:

```
    partial void CustomerDetail_Created()
        {
            Dispatchers.Main.BeginInvoke(() => ((INotifyPropertyChanged)this.Customer).PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged);
    }

    private void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Customer.Hidden)
        {
            case true:
                this.Customer.Hidden = true;
                this.Customer.BillingActive = false;
                break;

            case false:
                this.Customer.Hidden = false;
                this.Customer.BillingActive = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

But what if I want to change the value of a checkbox/other control in another screen? This partially works, if I use the same approach, but the screen that 'triggers' the change is not saved (or it appears not to save).

Comment: When you say it doesn't accomplish anything, what do you mean by that?  Is it not executing the code in Customer_Hidden?  You had said you want to set "Billing Active" and "Customer Reporting" to false if "Hidden" is set to true, but you never do that in your code; you only set the visibility.  What exactly is the logic you want to do here?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yeah, you are right - the way I am setting it won't accomplish what I aim for. My idea is that the controls are still visible, only their values are interchanged. So when I check "Hidden", the others (if true) are set to false. This is just an experiment, not so much of a real use case, but I was curious how to do it. I will spend some time now to figure it out (hopefully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no one to answer, I will post my own answer.

My initial approach was wrong - what I wanted to achieve is part of the business logic and not the screen logic. So it should be written in the entity instead of the screen. For the purpose I used the _Changed method with the property that is supposed to change:

```
    partial void Hidden_Changed()
    {
        foreach (Instance inst in this.Instances)
        {
            if (Hidden.Equals(true))
            {
                inst.UseForBilling = false;
                this.BillingActive = false;
            }
            else
            {
                inst.UseForBilling = true;
                this.BillingActive = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what event you have to use / which gets fired, when checking/unchecking the checkbox from the top of my head.
But, in any case you should not work on the controls and for sure not on the visibility. You should more work on the values of the current item to change those.
So try something like this:

```
Contacts.SelectedItem.BillingActive = false;
```

Kind regards
Simon